# WPF Button with Context Menu

Tags: wpf, button, contextmenu

I am new to WPF and am trying to bind a Context Menu to a Button with the Context Menu items coming from a View Model.

This is what I am doing:

```
<Button x:Name="btn" Content="Context Menu">
  <Button.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu x:Name="cm" ItemsSource="ItemsList"/>
  </Button.ContextMenu>
</Button>

private List<string> itemsList = null;
public List<string> ItemsList
{
  get
  {
    if(itemsList == null)
      itemsList = new List<string>(myStringArrayOfItems);
    return itemsList;                
  }
}
```

The XAML Editor keeps showing the error: The TypeConverter for "IEnumerable" does not support converting from a string.

What am I doing wrong here?

Also, assuming I get this working, what do I do to bind these items to a command and do some work when the item is clicked? I want to run the same command for all the menu items, just using the item string as a parameter.

Comment: Any ideas on this please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you do `ItemsSource="ItemsList"` you don't bind to `ItemsList` but set it to string `ItemsList`, hence your error. Try binding it like so:

```
<ContextMenu x:Name="cm" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ItemsList}"/>
```

as for the `Command` part you'll need some implementation of `ICommand` interface (like [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/d44932d3-ba6a-4ca1-88e0-c34665123a5c/implementation-relaycommand?forum=wpf)) and then you bind it like in `ItemContainerStyle`:

```
<ContextMenu ...>
   <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
         <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=PlacemantTarget.DataContext.ItemChanged }"/>
         <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
      </Style>
   </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu >
```

Comment: Thank you dkozl. I could get the data now. But for some reason, XAML keeps saying that "Command" is not a property that I can set. I guess I am doing something stupid, but not sure what.

Comment: try `<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">`

Comment: Though it is not throwing any error now, but the command is not getting fired. Probably we should not use the "ItemContainerStyle" here?

Comment: This is the place where you bind `Command`. Where is your command, one that you bind, defined? Is it another property of the class where `ItemsList` is defined?

Comment: Yes. I have it in the View Model as a ICommand Property as follows (I am using MVVM Light for the RelayCommand stuff):

public ICommand ItemChanged { get; set; }

//in the constructor
ItemChanged = new RelayCommand(ChangeItem);

public void ChangeItem()
{
  MessageBox.Show("Item Changed");
}

Comment: So you just need to change context. At the moment context for each item is the displayed string and you need to go up the visual tree where context it the list/command container class. I've update my answer. Now it should also pass bound string value to command call

Answer (score 2):

> xaml

```
<Button  Content="0k">
        <Button.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu x:Name="cm" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemsList}" />
        </Button.ContextMenu>
    </Button>
```

> xaml.cs

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
```

> ViewModel

```
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        ItemsList = new List<string> { "abc", "xyz" };
    }

    private List<string> itemsList = null;

    public List<string> ItemsList
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsList;
        }
        set
        {

            if (itemsList == null)
            {
                itemsList = value;
                Notify("ItemsList");
            }

        }
    }

    private void Notify(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

}
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Why I can't access `ContextMenu` by name from xaml.cs?